# What is the topology on the set of symmetric matrices?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, symmetric-matrices

What is the topology on the set of $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices?

So, it is claimed that the set of nonnegative definite matrices are closed, but what counts as an open set (topology) in this case?

(Kind of bonkers I can't find an answer to this elementary question by googling).

Comment: It's the subspace topology with respect to the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. So a limit is just an entrywise limit. It's very common to implicitly take the subspace topology like this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I see.

Comment: It's a metric space where the distance between $A$ and $B$ is defined to by $\operatorname{Tr}((A-B)^T(A-B))$

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.convexoptimization.com/wikimization/index.php/Positive_semidefinite_cone)